# I want to restore my back up into my sql database

Tags: java, mysql

I used foloowing code to back up my database from my sql which was run fine and got my back up in backup.sql.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

class Backup 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String command = "D:\\MySQL\\bin\\mysqldump.exe -u root -proot yatin -r D:/backup.sql"; 
        System.out.println(command);
        Process runtimeProcess;
        try 
        {
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
            if (processComplete == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
                //return true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

But when I executed below code it holds me in waiting state.
formarly my database name was yatin and now I want to restore it to mybackup database so I created database with name mybackup.
What's going wrong here

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

class Restore 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String command = "D:\\MySQL\\bin\\mysql.exe -u root -proot mybackup< D:/backup.sql";
        //String [] command = new String[]{"mysql",mybackup,"D:\\MySQL\\bin\\mysql.exe -u root -proot  < D:/backup.sql"; 
        //String[] command = new String[]{"mysql", [database], "--user=" + [username], "--password=" + [password], "-e", " source " + [absolute path to the sql file]};
        //String[] command = new String[]{"mysql",mybackup, "-u=" +root, "-p="+root, "-e", " source " +D:/backup.sql};
        System.out.println(command);
        Process runtimeProcess;
        try 
        {
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
            if (processComplete == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Restore created successfully");
                //return true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Could not restore");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

UPDATE 1

```
mysql> mysql -u root -proot mybackup < D:/backup.sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
 -u root -proot mybackup < D:/backup.sql' at line 1
```

Comment: Can you do it from the command line? Why do you need a java program to do this?

Comment: Any error messages? Why don't you just run the restore process via command line?

Comment: @user846476: from command line means? directly from my sql window. and I use java programme because to schedule a backup in schedule task

Comment: DaDaDom : No error. Just goes in to waiting state.

Comment: @user846476: As you said I tried it from command line . I added under update 1 edit. and got that error.

Answer (score 0):

This command should be outside of mysql console. You don't need to login in mysql and run this command, as `mysql -u root -p` already will do it for you.

`cmd > mysql -u root -proot mybackup < D:\backup.sql;`

Comment: if it's windows, then backward slash is needed. thx @user846476 for pointing out.

Comment: @Kalpesh Mehta: how you got that cmd >. I installed mysql on D: Drive. So I used it like D:\>mysql -u root -proot mybackup < D:\backup.sql; but it's not working . i am not able to restore backup.sql in database mybackup.

Comment: in Widnows go to start->run. Then type in cmd. The command prompt will open. Then do "cd d:\mysql\bin" if that is where the mysql.exe program is. Then run mysql -u root -proot mybackup < D:\backup.sql